# Mac Google Chrome iframe Access Parent Window

Tags: macos, iframe, google-chrome, window, parent

I am trying to access the parent window of an iframe and set the iframe's height.

The following code works on Windows IE7/IE8/Chrome/FireFox 3.6 and on Mac FireFox/Safari.

But on **Mac Chrome** it doesn't appear to be accessing the parent window.

On the parent page I have an iframe:

```
<iframe src="iframe_saleinfo.html" id="saleInformationIframe" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

In the iframe.html:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var theFrame = $('#saleInformationIframe', window.top.document);
    theFrame.height($(document.body).height() + 30);
});
```

I have also tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var theFrame = $('#saleInformationIframe', top.document);
    theFrame.height($(document.body).height() + 30);
});
```

And I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var theFrame = $('#saleInformationIframe', parent.document.body);
    theFrame.height($(document.body).height() + 30);
});
```

And I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var theFrame = $('#saleInformationIframe', window.parent.document);
    theFrame.height($(document.body).height() + 30);
});
```

Thanks in advance,

Jayde.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a local issue with Chrome Mac. I don't have a web server installed on the test mac but when I uploaded the files to a server and viewed it from there, everything appears to work.

Thanks,

Jayde.